# How to port Arduino Wire (I2C) read to STM32 HAL?

Tags: arduino, stm32, i2c, hal

I'm trying to translate an Arduino library for an STM32F4 Nucleo board (PN532 NFC controller for the records).

I'm stuck with the following code:

```
void NFC_Module::read_dt(uint8_t *buf, uint8_t len)
{
  delay(2);

  // Start read (n+1 to take into account leading 0x01 with I2C)
  Wire.requestFrom((u8)PN532_I2C_ADDRESS, (uint8_t)(len+2));
  // Discard the leading 0x01
  receive();
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
    delay(1);
    buf[i] = receive();
  }
}
```

And this is my current 'HAL version':

```
static uint8_t i2c_read(uint8_t reg)
{
  uint8_t ret = 0;
  HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c2, PN532_I2C_ADDRESS, reg, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &ret, 1, 1000);
  return ret;
}

void read_dt(uint8_t *buf, uint8_t len)
{
    HAL_Delay(10);

    // Start read (n+1 to take into account leading 0x01 with I2C)
    //Wire.requestFrom((uint8_t)PN532_I2C_ADDRESS, (uint8_t)(len+2));
    // Discard the leading 0x01
        i2c_read((len+2));     //receive();

    for (uint8_t i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        HAL_Delay(1);
        buf[i] = i2c_read((len+2));     //receive();
    }
}
```

which is probably wrong, as I do not understand the fact that there is no 'register' parameter in Arduino Wire.

Any help and/or corrections would be gladly accepted, many thanks !

Comment: the register is send before with write()